# Xcode licence must be accepted error when trying to select Xamarin Agent

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create my first iOS app using C# and Visual Studio 2017, and I am receiving the following error when trying to connect to the mac:

**"Xcode licence must be accepted in order to be connected and working against the Mac."**

I am assuming that this means I have to install Xcode on the mac, but I can't find any tutorials which mention this, or how to get started. Even if you go to the Microsoft documentation for Visual Studio 2017, linked to on this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx

you end up on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio

which mentions nothing about XCode, and tells you, "To get started, install Visual Studio 2015".

I have looked around for tutorials, but can't find any. I could just install XCode on the mac, but I don't want to run around just blindly installing things without knowing exactly what I'm doing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Think you need the Xcode command line tools to compile an iOS app. Thats independent of how you code. The tools are part of Xcode, but you can download and install them separately. see: https://mac-how-to.gadgethacks.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-without-xcode-0168115/ + download here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Install XCode, that's the most simple. When you launch it for the first time, it asks you some permissions, add-on installations and licence agreement if I remember well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when you have not installed XCode on your Mac or haven't accept it's licence.

(1) Install and start Xcode on the Mac

(2) If prompted to accept the Xcode license… Accept it.

If you find that you still can’t connect with the same message then you need to performs the following:

(1) Open Xcode > Preferences > Location

(2) Set the ‘Command Line Tools:’ to the latest Xcode version

(3) Open a Terminal window
Type

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

(4) Follow the instruction (press space bar till you get to the end, then type ‘agree’ and enter.

(5) Try to  reconnect the Mac Agent

Answer (score 0):

1. Use "xcode-select --install", as instructed by [enter link description here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569)
2. Switch the xcode "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" as instructed [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569)

It worked for me.